# Jenkins console output *********

Tags: jenkins, logging, agent

Has anyone faced these issues with Jenkins output logs?
I checked the jenkins pod log, it doesn't show any errors.
Inside the agent pod that executed the job, the log files are not showing these asterisks, it is normal.

```
****S********l********c****t********d**** ****G****i****t**** ****i****n****s****t****a****l****l****a****t****i****o****n**** ****d****o********s**** ****n****o****t************x****i****s****t****.**** ****U****s****i****n****g**** ****D********f****a****u****l****t************T****h************r********c****o****m****m********n****d********d********g****i****t*******t****o****o****l*******i****s****:*******N****O****N****E************u****s****i****n****g********c****r********d********n****t****i****a****l*******g****i****t****h****u****b****-**b********d****u****t********c****h************C****l****o****n****i****n****g**** ****t****h******** ****r********m****o****t******** ****G****i****t********r********p****o****s****i****t****o****r****y************C****l****o****n****i****n****g********r********p****o****s****i****t****o****r****y********h****t****t****p****s****:****/****/****g****i****t****h****u****b****.****c****o****m****/****b********d****u****t********c****h****/****r********s****t****-***a****p****i****************>********g****i****t**** ****i****n****i****t****
```

[LOG PRINT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlwLk.png)

Jenkins version: 2.14.3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't figure out how to solve this problem with the console output, basically all characters then with * .

Answer (score 0):

After updating Jenkins to some version after 2.361.4, this same issue in my Console Output log where it added "****" after every character started happening.

The issue was that I had a Jenkins Username/Password Credential (Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Credentials) with a blank Username. After adding a value to the username field, the issue with adding "****" after every character stopped.